# Angular 2: how to detect changes of property in services?

Tags: angularjs

Im using service to centralize my logic code, however i can't find a way on how to inform my other component when my property `_opened` in my service is being change..

**app.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core'; 

export class AsideService{
  _opened: boolean = true;

  _toggleSidebar() {
    this._opened = !this._opened;
     return this._opened;
  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<p (click)="_toggleSidebar()">
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AsideService } from '../aside.service';  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    open: any;

  constructor(private asideService: AsideService) {
    this.open = this.asideService._toggleSidebar();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways that you can do that. The most obvious reason would be to pass object containing `_opened` variable to the component. You would then have something like the following:

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core'; 

export class AsideService{
  _state: Object = {
     _opened: true
  };

  _toggleSidebar() {
    this._state._opened = !this._state._opened;
     return this._state;
  }

  _getState(){
    return this._state;
  }
}
```

and in your component, you would need to check for the value of `_state._opened` from service. This is because you can't pass the primitive values between the components - you need to surround them in an object. Then, for example in you component, you can go:

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    serviceState: any;
  constructor(private asideService: AsideService) {
    this.serviceState = this.asideService._toggleSidebar();
  }
}

and in your components HTML:

```
<div>{{serviceState._opened}}</div>
```

Which will show you the value of `_opened` in your service.

The other way would involve events, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: Thanks mate, but it gives me an error saying that cannot find name boolean. im new to angular 2..

Comment: change it to:          _opened: true

Comment: and also this mate `this._state._opened = !this._state._opened;` said that Property _opened does not exist on type Object.